# How do I Assert if statement which contains

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

I have value which in if statement contains equals but still it fails the test. please help to locate issue in the script.
 I need `if (383797)contains ($ 383,797)`
Test should pass

```
    // Database query to get value
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()){
        String mytotal = rs.getString(2);                                       
        System.out.println(mytotal);
        BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(mytotal);
        System.out.println(result+ " convert valueOf to int");

        // round of to million  
        System.out.println(result.divide(new BigDecimal("1000000")).setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR)+" Result 3");
        // Database data value
        String aarwavalue = (result.divide(new BigDecimal("1000000")).setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR)+"");
        System.out.println(aarwavalue);
        driver.switchTo().frame("mstrFrame");
        //Extract dynamic id for aarawtotal
        WebElement extractxpathid = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='AA RWA']"));
        System.out.println(extractxpathid.getAttribute("id"));
        String pathnum = extractxpathid.getAttribute("id");
        String[] xpathid = pathnum.split("-");
        System.out.println(xpathid[0]);
        System.out.println(xpathid[1]);
        System.out.println(xpathid[2]);
        // UI data 
        String aarwatotal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//td[@class='x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-"+xpathid[1]+" x-unselectable'])[last()]//div")).getText();
        System.out.println(aarwatotal);
        //assert UI value to database value 
        if(aarwatotal.contains(aarwavalue))
        {
            Reporter.log("Successfully  Database value equal UI value " + aarwatotal);
            Add_Log.info("Successfully  Database value equal UI value " + aarwatotal);
        }
        else
        {
            Reporter.log("  Database value  not equal UI value " + aarwatotal +"and"+ aarwavalue);
            Add_Log.info("Database value  not equal UI value " + aarwatotal +"and"+ aarwavalue);
            //  Assert.fail();
        }

        if(aarwavalue.equalsIgnoreCase(aarwatotal))
        {
            Reporter.log("Successfully  Database value equal UI value " + aarwatotal);
            Add_Log.info("Successfully  Database value equal UI value " + aarwatotal);
        }
        else
        {
            Reporter.log("  Database value  not equal UI value " + aarwatotal +"and"+ aarwavalue);
            Add_Log.info("Database value not equal UI value " + aarwatotal +"and"+ aarwavalue);
            //Assert.fail();
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT

```
 383797521414.9034250
 383797521414.9034250 convert valueOf to int
 383797 Result 3
 383797
 gridcolumn-1020-textEl
 gridcolumn
 1020
 textEl
 $ 383,797
   Database value  not equal UI value $ 383,797 and 383797
  Database value not equal UI value $ 383,797 and 383797
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value comparison returns `false`, that's why it fails the test.
The problem is with the comma `,`

You can manipulate the `String` `aarwatotal` to remove the comma like this:

```
String aarwatotal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//td[@class='x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-"+xpathid[1]+" x-unselectable'])[last()]//div")).getText();
//in the line below we replace the comma with empty String
aarwatotal = aarwatotal.replaceAll(",", "");
```

After that, `aarwatotal` will equal: `$ 383797` and you can now check if it contains `383797` correctly

The rest of the code can remain unchanged.